# WildCard for Object<String> in Java6

Tags: java, swing, generics, wildcard, jcombobox

Please how to correct casting and remove warning

```
[unchecked] unchecked cast
required:   T
found:      java.lang.Object
```

from SSCCE

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JComboBoxWithWildCard {

    private JDialog dlg = new JDialog();
    private final Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");

    public JComboBoxWithWildCard() {
        JComboBox comboWithCustomRenderer = new FlexiComboBox<String>(
                "1 one", "2 two", "3 three", "4 four", "5 five", "6 six",
                "7 seven", "8 eight", "9 nine", "10 ten", "11 eleven") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public String getCaption(String item) {
                return item;
            }

            @Override
            public Icon getItemIcon(String item) {
                return errorIcon;
            }
        };
        comboWithCustomRenderer.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        comboWithCustomRenderer.setMaximumRowCount(6);
        dlg.add(comboWithCustomRenderer);
        dlg.pack();
        dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dlg.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a_args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JComboBoxWithWildCard pd = new JComboBoxWithWildCard();
            }
        });
    }
}

abstract class FlexiComboBox<T> extends JComboBox {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FlexiComboBox(T... items) {
        super(items);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUI() {
        setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                Component result = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
                        getCaption((T) value), index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                Color color = getItemColor((T) value);
                if (color != null) {
                    result.setBackground(color);
                }
                if (result instanceof JLabel) {
                    ((JLabel) result).setIcon(getItemIcon((T) value));
                }
                return result;
            }
        });
        super.updateUI();
    }

    public abstract String getCaption(T item);

    public Color getItemColor(T item) {
        return null;
    }

    public Icon getItemIcon(T item) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Warning came from code lines

1.(codeline 70.th)

```
Component result = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
       getCaption((T) value), index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
```

2.(codeline 71.th)

```
Color color = getItemColor((T) value);
```

3.(codeline 76.th)

```
((JLabel) result).setIcon(getItemIcon((T) value));
```

Comment: which line did you get the warning on?

Comment: Are you sure this code gives that warning?? It's not giving any warning for me...

Comment: The thing is I don't think it can be fixed. You are casting to a generic type that you don't know (T). So as far as I can tell @SuppressWarning("unchecked") it must be...

Comment: @Thihara I think that possible, I saw there another woodoo, and this could be s pre_requisities for Generecs & Java7

Comment: Why are you casting these to T? Isn't it possible to go without the casting? I don't know what the methods are doing but it seems to me that you should be able to do things like getItemIcon(), getItemColor() without that cast. It you are depending on some implementation method perhaps you are better off using an interface there... Or restricting the type T.

Comment: @Thihara I can fills Object's_Model various ways as you described, but my curiosity 1) I'm want to know answer, 2) quite sure that's possible, 3) one quarter, maybe even more of my answers (here on this forum) is about how (somehting, whatever) that's possible

Comment: Well let me know if you find out how because casting to an unknown generic type is always unsafe as far as I can understand... But hey that's just me! :-D

Answer (score 2):

The warning is there because the compiler can not ensure that a `ClassCastException` won't be thrown. In this case, the following would cause an exception.

```
FlexiComboBox<Integer> box = new FlexiComboBox<Integer>();
box.addItem("BAD ITEM");
//then add the combobox to a panel and display it.
```

While it is not likely that you will write code that blatantly goes against the intent of the class you wrote, the compiler is warning you that this code could be misused.

The way you can hide the errors is to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to `getListCellRendererComponent`. This tells the compiler that you know there are risks, but you don't want them to be reported as a warning.

Comment: +1, for answer, I think that I understand this issue (not good in `Generics` & `Reflection`) my question is how to cast that correctly e.g. `<? whatever item>` e.i., to avoiding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: @mKorbel: unchecked casts are sometimes unavoidable, like in this case as you don't have `T` at runtime, so it is impossible to check it in that function

Comment: @newacct I'm really hope that you aren't right too, this is reason why this question I asked, and true is that I never saw unavoidable casting in Java, but true (too) is that I avoid to use Java7 ...