# Java Swing - How to create utils classes on Swing components with generics

Tags: java, swing, generics, java-7

I have a Utils class such that:

```
public static void setComboBoxDefaultWidth(JComboBox cb)
{
    cb.setPrototypeDisplayValue("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm");
}
```

The problem is that this results in a compiler warning:

**JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox should be parameterized**

I'm not sure how to parameterize the generic so that the calling method and the function both work (no compiler errors). I can resolve one but not both for whatever reason...

Comment: You could use something like `public static <T> void setComboBoxDefaultWidth(JComboBox<T> cb)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer that would not get you much further since <T> would remain "unknown" and therefore you could not invoke setPrototypeValue.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet You are right (of course), didn't realize that the `setPrototypeDisplayValue` took `<T>`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer its typing doesn't make sense that's why we wouldn't have thought it is typed ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't if you want to keep the JComboBox for any type of Generic.

Answer (score 4):

The fact is that `JComboBox` wasn't generic in Java6 but it became generic with 7 just because the design was flawed (since `getItemAt()` returned an Object type you had to manually cast it).

The method is declared as

```
public void setPrototypeDisplayValue(E prototypeDisplayValue)
```

This means that, you must have a specific instance of a specific class to call it, and the type must correspond to the one declared for your combo box:

```
public void setComboBoxDefaultWidth(JComboBox<String> cb) {
  cb.setPrototypeDisplayValue("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm");
}
```

You are forced to do it because you are passing a `String` to the method so the `JComboBox` must contain `String`s.

The above solution is what you need to do when the method that you want to invoke requires a parameter of the generics type. Otherwise you couldn't specify it (without narrwing how many the target) and you would have to use the wildcard `?` exists: if a method doesn't care about what is the specific type of the generic class you just need to specify that the `JComboBox` has a generic type without worrying about what the type is:

```
public static void setComboBoxDefaultWidth(JComboBox<?> cb) {
    cb.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(true);
}
```

The syntax `<?>` just literally means *unknown type*, the parameter is indeed a `JComboBox` of unknown type items.

Comment: This is wrong! setPrototypeDisplayValue is parameterized as well. If you use the '?' wildcard, you simply can't call setPrototypeValue! It needs to be a known type to invoke that method.

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't notice that setLightWeightPopupEnabled had a generic parameter. I just trusted on the fact that it required a string since it's related to an effective GUI layout (think about it, there is no actually need to pass an E, a String would be enough since it's just a prototype). This actually enforces you to generate a dummy object in certain situations, so I don't like how it's designed.

Comment: It is arguable why they had to add generics on UI-elements; in most case it is useless, at least on real-life examples. As for the prototype value, that's the way it has been designed and it is actually normal. You think only about rendering a label/string, but comboboxes can be used to render anything, not only String. Could be an icon, a complex component, etc... In those situation passing a String does not make sense. Passing the same objects allows to reuse the renderer and guarantee the consistency of the display. You can also not set any prototype value, that's what I do.

Comment: Yup, never set a prototype value but I'm still working in JSE6 in most situations so I never wondered about generics in it. Just noticed randomly one day that they switched to generics.

Comment: setting the prototype value is only useful if your combobox model actually contains a lot of entries (over a thousand) and/or if you perform rather complex rendering. The only purpose of that is to improve performance by avoiding to render each value of your combobox to determine the preferred size of the combobox. So this looks like really premature optimization in almost all cases.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype display value must of the same type as the one typing your JComboBox.

Given a `JComboBox<E>`, you can invoke the method `setPrototypeDisplayValue(E prototypeDisplayValue)` only if you know the type. Therefore, using a wildcard (?) is not an option. Currently, all you can do is to have:

```
public static void setComboBoxDefaultWidth(JComboBox<String> cb) {
    cb.setPrototypeDisplayValue("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm");
}
```

Another option you could have would be this:

```
public static <E> void setComboBoxDefaultWidth(JComboBox<E> cb, E prototypeValue) {
    cb.setPrototypeDisplayValue(prototypeValue);
}
```

but it is pointless.

Comment: [there are..., or I miss something ???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070688/wildcard-for-objectstring-in-java6)

Comment: @mKorbel I am not sure of what I should understand from your comment and the link you are pointing me to. Anyway, if you try Jack's answer, you will see immediately that it does not work. Using '?' means: you have a JComboBox that contains only a given type but I have no idea of which one. So it could contain Integer, Boolean, String, ... If for example, it were to contain Integer's, calling setPrototypeValue("mmmmmmmmmmmmm") would be awfully wrong. Eventually, the typed ListCellRenderer could end up throwing a ClassCastException: "String cannot be cast to Integer".

Comment: I think that implementations of Generics for Swing JComponents isn't correct, I can see simple implementations for model to view but rest (inherits and nested) isn't touched..., can't give complex answer for Sun APIs :-), because I'm not tried to compare, check API for ComboBox in JavaFX +1 for expanding rest of answers here

Comment: +1 - and taking the opportunity to rant a bit about the general uselessness of generics in ui ;-) It's fine in the model realm but nowhere else. All view-related building blocks can't really care: the renderer must be super E (aka: take everything, reflected in default renderer which is <Object>, the editor isn't typed at all). The prototypeValue is for the sole use of the not caring renderer .. so it's utter nonsense to type it ... </rant>

Answer (score 1):

If your `JComboBox`s always contains String, the syntax would be:

```
public static void setComboBoxDefaultWidth(JComboBox<String> cb)
{
    cb.setPrototypeDisplayValue("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm");
}
```

Comment: This is wrong! setPrototypeDisplayValue is parameterized as well. If you use the '?' wildcard, you simply can't call setPrototypeValue! It needs to be a known type to invoke that method.